# Puppeteer-cluster: many screenshots best practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I'm using Puppeteer-cluster to process a high volume of screenshots directly from various HTML strings, and the response should be ASAP in a few milliseconds.

Since opening and closing a browser for each screenshot is not efficient, we want to use a cluster of 10 browsers, and we saw that it gave us the wanted results in the processing speed.

My concerns are from memory piling up and I want to ask if any known best practices can be used to take care of that?

E.g:

1. Can the browsers in the cluster be refreshed?
2. Should we close the page after each screenshot?
   etc...

Thanks!